# Undefined index in $row

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am making a highscore webpage with tables. I've gotten two working so far and my last one is giving me trouble. The data is the time played and it is being stored in seconds. This is my query

Stuff I tried

```
    <?php if( isset($this->attr['totaltime'])) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['totaltime']; ?></td>

<?php   } ?>
```

I've tried a few different variations of this but none has worked for me. I believe it's my lack of knowledge and nothing else. I am 90% i need to add an `isset` in there to perform a check but I just dont know how the isset works and all the examples I found are extremely complicated.. Like this one.

```
$o = [];
@$var = ["",0,null,1,2,3,$foo,$o['myIndex']];
array_walk($var, function($v) {
    echo (!isset($v) || $v == false) ? 'true ' : 'false';
    echo ' ' . (empty($v) ? 'true' : 'false');
    echo "\n";
});
```

Comment: please dont edit your question like that, thats not how this site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second database column doesn't have a name, it's just the anonymous result of the Floor function.

You should use an *alias* for the column, e.g.

```
SELECT utime.playername, FLOOR(utime.totaltime / 3600) as totaltime FROM utime.utime ORDER BY utime.totaltime DESC LIMIT 10
```

This will then match the index name you're using to refer to it in the PHP

Comment: I love you so much thanks I didnt know you could do that!

Answer (score 0):

There is some debugging that I can suggest. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns the row as an associative array. And PHP provides a way to loop through an associative array that is the `foreach` loop.
What you can do is inside the body of the `while` loop, add the `foreach` loop

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($utimer)) {
              for ($row as $key -> $value){
                     echo "<br>Key: ". $key . " Value: ". $value
               }
  }
```

Remove the rest of the body of the `while` loop and let me know what did you get. The `$key` will contain the field name i.e. `totaltime` and `playername` and `$value` the data for that row. Let me know what you get.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This debugging advice, which is helpful in comments, but it's not an actual solution to the problem